# Promise silently fails

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

This promise silently fails and I've tried lots of different similar varieties without getting anywhere, no errors, nothing. Any ideas as to what could be wrong or how I might try to figure out what's wrong?

```
  function connectAndDo(appToken, doThis)
  {
    return window.fmApp.connect(appToken)
        .then(_ => doThis());
  }

  window.fmApp.initialize()
    .then((appToken) => connectAndDo(appToken, function(){console.log("function called");} ))
    .then(_ => console.log('afk'))
    .catch((err) => { console.error("Error from webapp: ", err); })
```

Comment: What are your actual and expected outputs?

Comment: Most probably the problem is inside one of the fmApp functions.

Comment: It runs until the connect function, then it doesn't run any on the "then"s anymore, it just stops, with no error. It doesn't run the doThis() function nor the console.log('afk')

Comment: put a console.log above `return window.fmApp.connect(appToken)` ... if that gets logged, and `function called` doesn't get logged, it's clear that whatever `window.fmApp.connect` is, never resolves or rejects - so it's not actually failing, it's just never resolving/rejecting - perhaps you could share with us what `fmApp` is

Comment: The console.log above gets logged and 'function called' doesn't. The connect function does some network calls, so maybe that fails somehow, but shouldn't I then get some error messages?